# Is there a way to authenticate Firebase users with a Python 3 backend?

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently working on an application with a Python 3 backend. Is it possible to authenticate users with Python 3 to get data from my Firestore database?

Comment: This question is very broad. Add more details so other users can help you better. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [A.S.H. answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58956973/209103), there is a Python *Admin* SDK to access Firestore from within Python code. This SDK it has full administrative access to your database based on a credentials file you download from the Firebase console. It does not require you to sign in as a user during the execution of the program.

So if you are looking to run a Python program on your own development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Function (altogether often referred to *trusted environments*{), you can use the Python Admin SDK to accomplish this.

If however you are looking to distribute the Python script to users of your application, then the Admin SDK is not suitable because it grants unrestricted access to the project's resources. In that case there is no SDK that allows the user to sign in with Firebase Authentication credentials. The best access in Python in that case is to use the [Firebase Authentication REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth).